# How to replace a specific node in multiple shaders?

Tags: materials, scripting, node-editor, shaders

So, My scene is quite vast, and all the things in the scene (Characters and props) have Principled BSDF node.

I recently found out about [Screen Space Ray Tracing](https://pedroplopes.itch.io/ssrt) node, made by *PedroPlopes*, which is a modified Principled BSDF, but it emulates a sort of Global Illumination effect (Like SSGI). I want to replace this node, with Principled BSDF on all the materials, and there are alot. Is there a simple way of doing it, rather than doing it manually?